# Error when running anything R related in Terminal

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I have some problems with R and Rstudio on a Ubuntu machine used by multiple users. I started trying to wipe it clean and reinstall evrything R related. But now when i run the "R" command in the Terminal I always get the following

`Warning: namespace 'rstan' is not available and has been replaced by .GlobalEnv when processing object '.__C__Rcpp_stan_fit4model11af1580473e_e075245664c44696e95a10d5e6ffcc15'`

Even though it is just a Warning I can't do anything at all.
Is there a way to uninstall everything related to R for all users and start of clean?

Comment: Do you have anything in ``~/.Rprofile``?

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain where this folder is supposed to be, I can't seem to find it

Comment: Do you still get warnings if you start like `R --vanilla` ? If not,  then when you start with `R` it may be loading a previous workspace.

Comment: When I start it with `R --vanilla` I don't get any warnings. Do you know how I can wipe R so all packages and workspaces etc.?

Comment: Have a look in your home directory for .Rdata or .Rds files. You can delete or it may be safer to rename (e.g. .Rdataold) if others are using. And remeber not to save your workspace when you close R. Or you could create an alias so that when you type R i nthe terminal it opens R -- vanilla